# Pytest object is not updated in an update view

Tags: python, django, pytest

My view **user_actions** allows to set an user inactive. Here is how:

```py
def user_update_details(request, username=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    if 'set_inactive' in request.POST:
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard_staff:user_details',
                            kwargs={'username': username}))
```

I use quite often this straightforward pattern and it works fine. I'd like to test it now. My user test is created as following.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def user(db) -> settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL:
    return UserFactory()
```

and the factory class:

```py
class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    username = Faker("user_name")
    email = Faker("email")
    first_name = Faker("first_name")
    last_name = Faker("last_name")

    @post_generation
    def password(self, create: bool, extracted: Sequence[Any], **kwargs):
        password = Faker(
            "password",
            length=42,
            special_chars=True,
            digits=True,
            upper_case=True,
            lower_case=True,
        ).generate(extra_kwargs={})
        self.set_password(password)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        django_get_or_create = ["username"]
```

Here is the test that fails:

```py
class TestUserActions:
    url = "dashboard_staff:user_actions"

    def test_set_user_inactive(self, user):
        assert user.is_active
        url = reverse(self.url, kwargs={'username': user.username})
        resp = Client().post(url, data={'set_inactive': ''}, follow=True)
        assert resp.status_code == 200
        user.refresh_from_db()
        assert user.is_active is False
```

and the exception:

```
        assert customer_manager.is_active
E       assert False
E        +  where False = <Customer: Adrian Huynh>.is_active
```

Comment: What if you slap a `print('It changed!')` in that view (and run `py.test -s ...` to not have it capture stdout)? Does that output appear?

Comment: By the way, your exception shows an object called `customer_manager`  not in any of the other snippets...

Comment: Test passed correctly if I get rid of the ```follow=True``` and test for the redirection ```status_code==302``` instead of ```status_code==200```. In this case, my object user is updated. I wish to understand why !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment, I found a workaround. For an unknown reason, it seems that the view doesn't update the instance if we use the `follow=True` parameter. So, in order to test it:

```py
class TestUserActions:
    url = "dashboard_staff:user_actions"

    def test_set_user_inactive(self, user):
        assert user.is_active
        url = reverse(self.url, kwargs={'username': user.username})
        resp = Client().post(url, data={'set_inactive': ''})
        assert resp.status_code == 302
        user.refresh_from_db()
        assert user.is_active is False
```

Instead of testing `status_code == 200`, I simply check the redirection and that the instance is corretly update.